# Unable to initialise Sisyphus

Tags: jquery, forms, save

I am having a really irritating issue. I am not too familiar with Javascript syntax or jQuery since the web apps I build are mainly PHP/HTML. I am trying to implement Sisyphus so I can save my form data, but I can't get it to initialise. I've had the console open whilst the form loads after entering data, but it goes away when I reload and I can't see any entries in the 'Web Storage' section. My code is as follows:

```
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/scripts/sisyphus.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     $(window).load(function() {
        $('form').sisyphus(
            {
                locationBased: true,
                timeout: 0
            }
        );
    });
</script>
```

This does not work. I've tried including it in the body and head, but it won't work. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? So simple yet so frustrating!

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of $(windows).load:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but it didn't work. When I refresh i still see nothing in web storage. The above code is taken from another post regarding Sisyphus on Stack Overflow, but their issue was syntactical. Mine just doesn't seem to work. I've tried it in Firefox and Chrome but get the same.

Comment: can you debug that? if not try to put it in an external js file so you can see if the sisyphus function is recognized

Comment: I am not sure how to debug it, I have Chrome's console open and no errors are showing. The local storage isn't being used at all either.